# Can I add our company Sharepoint portal URL to always show in File Open/Save dialog?

Tags: windows-10, sharepoint, sharepoint-server-2019

We have on-premises Sharepoint Server 2019. When I open a file *from* SP in Word, and do "save as" then the SP is shown as a save location like the following https://portal.GreatWidgets.com/sites/GWS/XYZ

But if I open an application normally and want to save/load a file to/from SP the location isn't listed. I can manually type in the URL to the Save/load files dialog but this is a bit ugly.

Should I be able to integrate SP as a default location on my computer somehow?

Comment: Do you see a Sites list under your corporate domain, in the Save/Save As/Save A Copy page? Should be top left.

Comment: Try to open the URL in Windows Explorer, right-click it and select "Pin to Quick Access".

Comment: @spikey_richie sometimes but only in Office apps it seems, I have a feeling our SP setup missed a step but trying to resolve through corporate IT... would rather just fix it locally.